# How to change iconbutton to it's default backcolor when clickevent is not performed?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, backcolor, iconbutton

I have 20 iconbuttons in my form. when clickevent is performed i want to change buttons(backcolor,forecolor,Iconcolor) and remaining buttons should revert to it's default color.

```
 public void btn1()
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    (c as Button).ForeColor = Color.White;
                    (c as Button).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(46, 51, 73);

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make each button listen to the same Click event and do some conditional logic to achieve this.

First, make each of your buttons reference the same click event.  You can do this from the Form Designer by clicking the button and in the Properties window, click the lightening bolt icon (the events icon) and change the Click event to be the method you wish:

[image: properties window showing the events list and click event]

Then, make your event method do something like this:

```cs
public void ChangeButtonColors(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //change the color of the clicked button to desired color
    Button clickedButton = (System.Windows.Forms.Button)sender;
    clickedButton.BackColor = Color.Red;

    //change all other buttons to defualt color
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is Button && c != clickedButton)
        {
            c.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

This gets the type of the `sender` (the clicked button in this case), and sets the `BackColor` property of it. Then, the `foreach` loop loops over all of the controls in the form, checks if the current item in the list is a button and **is not** the button that was clicked, it will change the `BackColor` property. Obviously, you can change other properties of both the clicked button, and the other buttons in the `foreach`.

If done properly, this is how it should behave:

[image: gif illustrating how clicking the buttons change the colors of them]

Answer (score 0):

This is what `RadioButton` is good for. Just set its `Appearance` to `Button` so it will look like a regular button but will act as a radio button: clicking it unchecks all the other buttons. The `Checked` property will be `true` for only the lastly clicked button:

[image]

Comment: Don't the radio buttons have to be in a group (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-group-windows-forms-radiobutton-controls-to-function-as-a-set?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN)) for this to work? How else would the application be aware of when one is checked, the others aren't/need to be unchecked (aside from writing an event listener)?

Comment: If their parent is the same form/panel/groupbox other control, then they behave as illustrated. The OP iterates on `this.Controls`, which tells that they share the same parent, ie. they are in a group.